# Application stops after swiping

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an app reader like `Apple Books`. And I have a problem. I have `NavigationViewController` next `FirstViewController` with book button, `SecondViewController` it is a reader and `TableViewController` it is settings for text size. But if I open book in `FirstViewController` go to `SecondViewController` and in navigation bar tab `aA` button and open `TableViewController` all works fine. But after if I want back to `FirstViewController` I not close `TableViewController` and do swipe from left to right my app stops. How to fix it?

[image]

SecondViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textSettings: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupGestures()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Text Settings View
    
    private func setupGestures() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        textSettings.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc private func tapped(){
        guard let popVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popVC") else { return }
        popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        let popOverVC = popVC.popoverPresentationController
        popOverVC?.delegate = self
        popOverVC?.sourceView = self.textSettings
        popOverVC?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.textSettings.bounds.midX, y: self.textSettings.bounds.maxY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 250)
        
        self.present(popVC, animated: true)
    }
}

extension SecondViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

Other controllers have no special code. Video illustrating the problem - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HUV26H4VFoKglh8FbkNP0y2Y3rYl4Q_f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you have a UINavigationController in your view hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not showing it

Comment: How is First View Controller being presented though?

Comment: @clawesome `NavigationViewController`(UINavigationController) -> `FirstViewController`(UIViewController) -> `SecondViewController`(UIViewController) -> `TableViewController`(UITableViewController)

Comment: Are you hiding the navigation bar in your first controller?  Otherwise, I would expect it to have a navigation bar if it's a child controller of a UINavigationController

Comment: No, - https://ibb.co/qpWdr11

Comment: @clawesome I can send you a project. It is help to understand the problem?

Comment: @clawesome please tell me what should I do to make the question clearer? Share a project or else?

Comment: If you could share a repo on Github, that would definitely help.